# Linking maps using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, link

I am trying to show a 4 panel map, each with a different dataset. So far I have this, but the maps do not seem to be linked and the layers are not loading.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
    //////////NO2///////////
var NO2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
            .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
            .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2020-05-30')

// Make predefined data layers that can be selected.
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes');
var palette = palettes.colorbrewer.BrBG[11].reverse();

var NO2_band_viz = {
  min: 30,
  max: 300,
  palette: palette,
  opacity: 0.8
};

///population
var pop = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop")


/////nighttime lights/////
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-05-01', '2020-05-31'));
var nighttime = dataset.select('avg_rad');
var nighttimeVis = {min: 0.0, max: 60.0};



// Create a map for each visualization option.
var map1 = ui.Map()
map1.add(ui.Label('NO2'))
map1.addLayer(NO2, NO2_band_viz, 'NO2')
map1.setControlVisibility(true);

var map2 = ui.Map()
map2.add(ui.Label('Population'))
map2.addLayer(pop, {}, 'Population')
map2.setControlVisibility(true);

var map3 = ui.Map()
map3.add(ui.Label('Nighttime Lights'))
map3.addLayer(nighttime, nighttimeVis, 'Nighttime Lights')
map3.setControlVisibility(false);

var map4 = ui.Map()
map4.add(ui.Label('NO2'))
map4.addLayer(NO2, NO2_band_viz, 'NO2')
map4.setControlVisibility(false);

var linker = ui.Map.Linker(map1, map2, map3, map4);

// Enable zooming on the top-left map.
map1.setControlVisibility({zoomControl: true});

// Show the scale (e.g. '500m') on the bottom-right map.
map3.setControlVisibility({scaleControl: true});

// Create a grid of maps.
var mapGrid = ui.Panel(
    [
      ui.Panel([map1, map2], null, {stretch: 'both'}),
      ui.Panel([map3, map4], null, {stretch: 'both'})
    ],
    ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'), {stretch: 'both'});

// Center the map at an interesting spot in Greece. All
// other maps will align themselves to this parent map.
map1.setCenter(21.2712, 38.4151, 12);


/*
 * Add a title and initialize
 */

// Create a title.
var title = ui.Label('Title', {
  stretch: 'horizontal',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: '24px'
});

// Add the maps and title to the ui.root.
ui.root.widgets().reset([title, mapGrid]);
ui.root.setLayout(ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('vertical'));
```

Link to code here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/59c837c11e763ae298097a4a15911c08

Answer (score 1):

`ui.Map.Linker` takes a list of maps.

```
var linker = ui.Map.Linker(map1, map2, map3, map4);
```

should instead be

```
var linker = ui.Map.Linker([map1, map2, map3, map4]);
```

Comment: thank you! @Kevin Reid

Comment: The layers are still not loading.. do you have a solution? https://code.earthengine.google.com/9d51d9240f70e2c3b527d33fdd1ccb74

Comment: @aewindle They load for me but the NO2 `map1` is very slow to load and the others don't start loading any until the first has some finished.